# Laravel authentication not persistent

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to make alive again an old project using `Laravel 5.4` and Laravel Valet.

I'm facing an issue with authentication.

### LoginController

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, User $user){
        $previous_session = $user->session_id;
        if ($previous_session) {
            Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->session_id = Session::getId();
        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user, true);
        return redirect('testlogin');
    }
```

### Routes

```
Route::get('testlogin', function () {
    dd(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check());
});
```

In the LoginController, `$user` is retrieved and not `null`, but as soon as a redirection is made `Auth::check()` is `false`

#### Questions

What's wrong ? I cannot make make up my mind on this

Comment: Can you provide more console logs or debug infos?

Answer (score 1):

This drove me crazy a few times as well.  Most likely your 'testLogin' route is not contained within the auth middleware, which would not give you auth at the time of the route passing.  If this is the case, move your 'testLogin' route inside the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { ... HERE ... }
```

Comment: It is not under auth middleware, but now I cannot access the route at all. Because specifically of the auth middleware I think

Answer (score 0):

In the `.env` file, the variable `SESSION_DOMAIN` was not set properly and did not reflect the local domain (which had changed between now and few years ago)... Stupid error but I hope it might prevent others to do the same.